# How to preserve #hashtag and @mention characterizers from Countvectorizer token_pattern

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tokenize, hashtag, countvectorizer

I use sklearn library for extracting word count from tweets. But I have a problem with dropping some specials chars. I want to preserve '#' and '@' chars from `CountVectorizer` object.

The default token_pattern parameter is: `token_pattern='(?u)\b\w\w+\b'`

For example on this corpus...

```
['@terör @terör #terör ak @terör ali ali ...']
```

...the output is:

```
['ak', 'ali', 'terör', ...]
```

`CountVectorizer`'s default regex removes special chars. How can I preserve these chars?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I change the parameter with ;

```
token_pattern=r'\b\w\w+\b|(?<!\w)@\w+|(?<!\w)#\w+')
```

The output comes as desired;

```
['@terör', '#terör', ...]
```